# How to get the length of the unique array elements of an JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have a JSON array of users with product and user_status, how to get the length of only active users from the below JSON array

```
{
  "body": {
    "existing_users": [
      {
        "product": "Pack-2",
        "user_status": "Inactive"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-1",
        "user_status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-3",
        "user_status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-5",
        "user_status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-1",
        "user_status": "Inactive"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-1",
        "user_status": "Active"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the above JSON array has a list of both active and Inactive users , I want to get the count of the active users from the JSON array.

I tried using the spread operator

```
console.log(...this.user.body.existing_users);
```

Which gives the list of all the users how can add the condition and get only active user

[stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-laazp3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
getLengthOfActiveUser() {
  const activeUsers = this.user.body.existing_users.filter(
    user => user.user_status === 'Active'
  );

  console.log(activeUsers.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method to filter out Inactive users.

```
const active_users = this.user.body.existing_users.filter(user => user.user_status !== "Inactive")
console.log(...active_users);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const res = {
  "body": {
    "existing_users": [
      {
        "product": "Pack-2",
        "user_status": "Inactive"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-1",
        "user_status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-3",
        "user_status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-5",
        "user_status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-1",
        "user_status": "Inactive"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-1",
        "user_status": "Active"
      }
    ]
  }
}

console.log(res.body.existing_users.filter(user => user.user_status === "Active").length)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var JSONobject = { 
"body": {
    "existing_users": [
      {
        "product": "Pack-2",
        "user_status": "Inactive"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-1",
        "user_status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-3",
        "user_status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-5",
        "user_status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-1",
        "user_status": "Inactive"
      },
      {
        "product": "Pack-1",
        "user_status": "Active"
      }
    ]
  }
}
}

function countActive(){
    var count = 0;
    for(i=0;i<=JSONobject.body.existing_users.length - 1;i++){
        if(JSONobject.body.existing_users[i].user_status == 'Active'){
            count++
        }
        
    }
    console.log(count);
}
countActive();
```

You loop through the object and test if the user status is active. If so, you raise the counter by one. After the loop is finished, the count variable holds the amount of active users.

If you want a list of all the active users, you can do something like this:

```
function countActive(){
    var activeUsers = [];
    for(i=0;i<=JSONobject.body.existing_users.length - 1;i++){
        if(JSONobject.body.existing_users[i].user_status == 'Active'){
            activeUsers.push(JSONobject.body.existing_users[i]);
        }
        
    }
    console.log(activeUsers);
}
```

here, the array activeUsers holds all the objects of active users.